# How to get word embeddings back from Keras?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, word-embedding

Say you create your own custom word embeddings in the process of some arbitrary task, say text classification. How do you get a dictionary like structure of `{word: vector}` back from Keras?

`embeddings_layer.get_weights()` gives you the raw embeddings...but it's unclear which word corresponds to what vector element.

Answer (score 1):

This dictionary is not a part of keras model. It should be kept separately as a normal python dictionary. It should be in your code - you use it to convert text to integer indices (to feed them to Embedding layer).

Comment: Interesting design choice; thanks for the potential clarification